# How to import KML with osmdroid?

Tags: android, openstreetmap, osmdroid

I have project that need show KML in maps, i already done it in google maps, but it seem too slow and sometimes it force close.
I have searched it, they need convert the KML to GPX, isn't it same like KML or different?

[image]

Now i try osmdroid for other solution, but there is few references about importing KML with osmdroid.
Do you know how i can import KML with osmdroid?

Answer (score 3):

Full Sample:

app/build.gradle:

```
android{
...
    repositories{
        ...
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
...
}
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'org.osmdroid:osmdroid-android:5.6.5'
    compile 'com.github.MKergall:osmbonuspack:6.4'
}
```

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private MapView mapView;
    private IMapController mapController;
    private Context context;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        context = this;
        mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
        mapView.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.MAPNIK);
        mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        mapController = mapView.getController();
        mapController.setZoom(15);
        GeoPoint point2 = new GeoPoint(51496994, -134733);
        mapController.setCenter(point2);

        loadKml();
    }

    public void loadKml() {
        new KmlLoader().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
    }

    class KmlLoader extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        KmlDocument kmlDocument;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            progressDialog.setMessage("Loading Project...");
            progressDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            kmlDocument = new KmlDocument();
            kmlDocument.parseKMLStream(getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.kmlfile), null);
            FolderOverlay kmlOverlay = (FolderOverlay)kmlDocument.mKmlRoot.buildOverlay(mapView, null, null,kmlDocument);
            mapView.getOverlays().add(kmlOverlay);
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            mapView.invalidate();
            BoundingBox bb = kmlDocument.mKmlRoot.getBoundingBox();
            mapView.zoomToBoundingBox(bb, true);
//            mapView.getController().setCenter(bb.getCenter());
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        }
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.sample.osmdroid.osmdroidsample.MainActivity">

    <org.osmdroid.views.MapView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/mapView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:clickable="true"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Add following permissions in Manifest:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Comment: Works fine but I'm getting a message "This AsyncTask class should be static or leaks might occur (com.example.map3.MainActivity.KmlLoader) " - and of course if it's made static I can't access the non-static mapView.

Answer (score 2):

[osmbonuspack](https://github.com/MKergall/osmbonuspack) can handle KML files. See [Tutorial 4](https://github.com/MKergall/osmbonuspack/wiki/Tutorial_4) for an example on how to show a KML file on your map.